# Can't resolve warning in Gradle 6.4

Tags: java, gradle

In Gradle 6.4 i've got warning with type as:

```
    > Configure project :
The testCompile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the testImplementation configuration instead. Consu
lt the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_c
onfigurations
```

But i've changed all my compile and testCompile declaration to implementation, but problem doesn't want to disappear just the same

My build.gradle file:

I can't find the problem below

```
plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version "2.4"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"
}


allure {
    version = '2.4'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = '2.0-BETA9'
}


apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: "io.qameta.allure"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:6.11'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.6.0'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
    implementation 'com.beust:jcommander:1.72'
    implementation 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
    implementation 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0'
    implementation 'ru.yandex.qatools.ashot:ashot:1.5.4'
    implementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'


//    DB
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.10.Final")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.16")


    /*def excludeLog = {exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'}
    compile 'net.sourceforge.tess4j:tess4j:4.2.2', excludeLog*/
    /*def excludeLog = {exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'}*/
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.tess4j:tess4j:4.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '3.0.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'


    //Gmail
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev83-1.23.0'

    //ftp client
    implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.6'
}

task testSitecheckerDB(type: Test) {
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsalt', "${pswsalt}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsk', "${pswsk}"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/dbTests/testng-sitechecker-position-test.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task testSitecheckerNewUI(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/SCnew.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task crawlerTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/sitechecker-crawling-test.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task noMonitoringTest(type: Test) {
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsalt', "${pswsalt}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsk', "${pswsk}"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/dbTests/noMonitoringTest.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task inProgressDomainsTest(type: Test) {
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsalt', "${pswsalt}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsk', "${pswsk}"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/dbTests/testng-sitechecker-inProgressDomain-test.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task userWorkFlowTest(type: Test) {
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsalt', "${pswsalt}"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('pswsalt')) {
        systemProperty 'pswsk', "${pswsk}"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testNG/testng-sitechecker-prod-UserWorkFlowtest.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
}
```

Maybe someone understand where the problem is? Or can guess me, where can i see exact warning code line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root of the problem. Allure plugin use 'testCompile' by default. Fixed it by adding configuration in allure:

```
allure {
    version = '2.4'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = '2.0-BETA9'
    configuration = 'testImplementation'
}
```